# How to Remove default rich-tabhdr-side-border in tab panel in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm using Tab panel in my page and using two tabs.
All functions are working properly, lightly design issue came in the apex:tabpanel.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false"> 
    <style>
        .rich-tabhdr-side-border { display: none; background-image: none; }
    </style>

    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" contentStyle="rich-tabhdr-side-border">
        <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne" >content for tab one</apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo">content for tab two</apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It is not really clear what are you asking. Can you explain and give more details?

Answer (score 0):

Your visualforce markup is wrong where you are using the `contentStyle` attribute.

You should add an **inline CSS** into it:

> [used primarily for adding inline CSS styles.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm)

So it should looks like this:

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" contentStyle="display:none; background-image:none;">
```

Otherwise use `contentClass` attribute for assign an CSS Class to the content.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Based on the code given.

Comment: Thanks @mast0r, But still deign issue  will occur, its never disable the default tab class "rich-tabhdr-side-border"